# Редирект c .html/ на без html и без слэша

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Как сделать редирект со страниц .html на страницы без html и также со слешем на конце на без слеша?

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
DirectorySlash Off

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /[^?\s]+\.html
RewriteRule (.*)\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*)/$ $1.html [L]

# Remove trailing slash:
RewriteRule (.*)/$ $1 [L,R=301]

# Now test without the trailing slash:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.(html?)$ /$1 [R=301,NC,L]
</IfModule>

<Files .htaccess>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files>

ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
ErrorDocument 403 /404.html
```

Answer (score 2):

## Стандартный .htaccess

Для единообразия формирования URL страниц сайтов, и предотвращения появлений дубликатов страниц, вводится стандартная часть файла .htaccess

### Данный конфиг позволяет решить следующие задачи:

- Активация канонических директив
- Установить основное зеркало сайта с www или без него с учетом сохранения http или https
- Удалить любое количество "/" стоящих рядом до 1 ///--> /
- Удалять "/" в конце URL если это файл
- Добавлять "/" в конце URL если его там нет и это не файл
- Удалить из URL index.php
- Требования google page speed

### Последовательность установки:

1. Вставить код в начале .htaccess
2. При вставке требуется указать правильное зеркало сайта, раскоментировав нужное
3. Удалить старый redirect перенаправление на основное зеркало.
4. Проверить все новые redirect(ы) на  правильную работу  в условиях данного проекта.

### Код конфигурационного файла каталога .htaccess.

```
############################################################################
#### Стандартный .htaccess для проектов студии Клондайк, версия 3.6     ####
############################################################################
RewriteEngine On
   #  Директива включает редиректы.
RewriteBase / 
   # Без директивы (.*) = /$1 будет /var/wwww/site/web/$1  с директивой  = /$1
Options +FollowSymLinks
   # Разрешает переход по символическим ссылкам.
php_flag display_errors off
  # запретить отображение ошибок  (требование монитора качества)
php_flag allow_url_fopen off
  # запретить  использовать удаленые файлы (требование проактивной защиты)

############################################################################
#### Выбор основного зеркала (с www или без www)                        ####
############################################################################
    # 1. Удалить www
#RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} on
    #Если включен https
#RewriteRule .* - [E=SSL:s]
    #То создаем переменную  ssl с текстом s
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
    # Проверяем, содержит ли домен www в начале URL.
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http%{ENV:SSL}://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
    # Перенаправляем удаляем www

    # 2. Добавить www
#RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} on
    #Если включен https
#RewriteRule .* - [E=SSL:s]
    #То создаем переменную  ssl с текстом s
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*) [NC]
    # Если нет www в начале домена
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http%{ENV:SSL}://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
    #Подставляем www и https если он включен.

############################################################################
#### Перенаправляем протокол https на http                              ####
############################################################################
#RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} on
   # Проверяем наличие https в URL.
#RewriteRule ^.*$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
   # Перенаправляем протокол на http.

############################################################################
#### Перенаправляем протокол http на https                              ####
############################################################################
#RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on
   # Проверяем наличие https в URL.
#RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
   # Перенаправляем протокол на http.

############################################################################
#### Убираем повторяющиеся слеши (/) в URL                              ####
############################################################################
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} //
   # Проверяем, повторяется ли слеш (//) более двух раз.
RewriteRule .* /$0 [R=301,L]
   # Исключаем все лишние слеши.

############################################################################
#### Убираем слеши в конце URL для статических файлов (содержит точку)  ####
############################################################################
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \..+$
   # Если файл содержит точку.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   # И это не директория.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
   # Является файлом.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)/$
   # И в конце URL есть слеш.
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
   # Исключить слеш.

############################################################################
#### Добавляем слеш(/), если его нет, и это не файл.                    ####
############################################################################
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
   # Если слеша в конце нет.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   # Не является файлом.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\..+$
   # В URL нет точки (файл).
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [L,R=301]
   # Добавляем слеш в конце.

############################################################################
#### Убираем index.php, если он есть в конце URL                        ####
############################################################################
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} =GET
   # Выявляем GET запрос в URL (не POST).
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/index\.php$
   # URL cодержит index.php в конце.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %1/ [R=301,L]
   # Удалить index.php из URL.

############################################################################
#### Компрессия статического контента для гугл  спид тест               ####
############################################################################
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  AddType image/svg+xml .svg
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml  
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive on
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 3 day"
  ExpiresByType image/svg "access plus 3 day"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 3 day"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 3 day"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 3 day"
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 3 day"
  ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 3 day"
</IfModule>

############################################################################
#### Антивирус, только для 1С-Битрикс,                                  ####
############################################################################
#php_value auto_prepend_file "/home/bitrix/ext_www/SITE.RU/bitrix/modules/security/tools/start.php"
   #  укажите путь до файла 
   # включить тут /bitrix/admin/security_antivirus.php?lang=ru

############################################################################
#### Конец общей части, далее следует собственные директивы .htaccess   ####
############################################################################
```

> **Пруфлинк:** [**«Студия Клондайк»**](https://klondike-studio.ru/standards/standartnyy-htaccess/)

Comment: спасибо. но не работает, почему то

Comment: Нашёл в интернетах статью, с довольно подробным разбором файла .htaccess. Надеюсь она поможет. Удачи!

Answer (score 1):

PHP:

```
$url = (isset($_GET['q'])) ? $_GET['q'] : '';
$url = rtrim($url, '/');
```

.htaccess:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```